# Nodejs - Value input POST request not assigned (using Postman)

Tags: node.js, post

I'm newbie and I'm creating an API using Nodejs, MongoDB as DB and trubo360 as a deployment environment. I already make my post request script. But when I test it with Postman, it not assign the value. It just assign the default value which is I set it on my model class. And it not throwing any error. Here is the my post request test with postman :

Input value :
[image]

Request response :

[image]

My post request script :

**routes/api.js :**

```
// POST - create new entities :
router.post('/:resource', (req, res) => {
    const resource = req.params.resource
    const controller = controllers[resource]

    if(resource == null) {
        res.json({
            confirmation: 'fail',
            message: 'Invalid resource'
        })

        return
    }else {
        controller.post(req.body)
        .then(data => {

    console.log(req)
            res.json({
                confirmation: 'success',
                data: data,
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.json({
                confirmation: 'fail',
                message: err.message
            })
        })
    }
})
```

and this is my controller 
**controllers/PlayerController.js :**

```
post: (params) => {
        console.log(params)
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
            Player.create(params)
            .then(data => {
                resolve(data)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                reject(err)
            })
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't pass data up in the body of the request, you pass it up as query string parameters, therefore you need to use [`req.query`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query):

```
controller.post(req.query);
```

Comment: @AlifRamdani no problem, FWIW the information you do send may be better served in the body of the request. Look at [express.urlencoded](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded).